# Stellar-core not syncing on testnet after restart. Missing Buckets not being retrieved

Tags: stellar-core, testnet, history, error, buckets

After attempting to restart a stellar core node I had running on the test net I got an error, and when I tried to run stellar-core (inside docker container) with `stellar-core run`
I got the following:

```
2019-02-22T12:04:46.479 <startup> [default INFO] Assigning calculated value of 0 to FAILURE_SAFETY
2019-02-22T12:04:46.483 GBRCX [default INFO] Starting stellar-core v10.1.0
2019-02-22T12:04:46.483 GBRCX [Database INFO] Connecting to: postgresql://dbname=core host=localhost user=stellar password=********
2019-02-22T12:04:46.490 GBRCX [SCP INFO] LocalNode::LocalNode@GBRCX qSet: 273af2
2019-02-22T12:04:46.490 GBRCX [default INFO] Listening on 0.0.0.0:11626 for HTTP requests
2019-02-22T12:04:46.491 GBRCX [History INFO] Archive 'cache' has 'get' command only, will not be written
2019-02-22T12:04:46.491 GBRCX [History INFO] Archive 'h1' has 'get' command only, will not be written
2019-02-22T12:04:46.492 GBRCX [History INFO] Archive 'h2' has 'get' command only, will not be written
2019-02-22T12:04:46.492 GBRCX [History INFO] Archive 'h3' has 'get' command only, will not be written
2019-02-22T12:04:46.492 GBRCX [History WARNING] No writable archives configured, history will not be written.
2019-02-22T12:04:46.492 GBRCX [Ledger INFO] Starting up application
2019-02-22T12:04:46.492 GBRCX [default INFO] Loading last known ledger
2019-02-22T12:04:46.494 GBRCX [Ledger WARNING] Some buckets are missing in 'buckets'.
2019-02-22T12:04:46.494 GBRCX [Ledger WARNING] Attempting to recover from the history store.
2019-02-22T12:04:46.494 GBRCX [History INFO] Starting RepairMissingBucketsWork
cp: cannot stat '/opt/stellar/history-cache/bucket/10/04/21/bucket-100421672673d39259eac3b4b00e8c33cf35abbf28098a1c3ba4132fe34c69c6.xdr.gz': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/opt/stellar/history-cache/bucket/4a/da/12/bucket-4ada1209069c7130d0b5b06928caaa0f824415e962e7a60a6bb485c99ee07fe3.xdr.gz': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/opt/stellar/history-cache/bucket/de/af/8a/bucket-deaf8aeb4c53142864edd814425bb14a45fae3f36dea1557e88aae1c972e732b.xdr.gz': No such file or directory
2019-02-22T12:04:46.513 GBRCX [Process WARNING] process 30117 exited 1: cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/bucket/10/04/21/bucket-100421672673d39259eac3b4b00e8c33cf35abbf28098a1c3ba4132fe34c69c6.xdr.gz buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2b62dacdf80bb2d4/bucket-100421672673d39259eac3b4b00e8c33cf35abbf28098a1c3ba4132fe34c69c6.xdr.gz.tmp
2019-02-22T12:04:46.513 GBRCX [Process WARNING] process 30118 exited 1: cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/bucket/4a/da/12/bucket-4ada1209069c7130d0b5b06928caaa0f824415e962e7a60a6bb485c99ee07fe3.xdr.gz buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2b62dacdf80bb2d4/bucket-4ada1209069c7130d0b5b06928caaa0f824415e962e7a60a6bb485c99ee07fe3.xdr.gz.tmp
2019-02-22T12:04:46.513 GBRCX [Process WARNING] process 30124 exited 1: cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/bucket/de/af/8a/bucket-deaf8aeb4c53142864edd814425bb14a45fae3f36dea1557e88aae1c972e732b.xdr.gz buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2b62dacdf80bb2d4/bucket-deaf8aeb4c53142864edd814425bb14a45fae3f36dea1557e88aae1c972e732b.xdr.gz.tmp
2019-02-22T12:04:46.513 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/10/04/21/bucket-100421672673d39259eac3b4b00e8c33cf35abbf28098a1c3ba4132fe34c69c6.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.513 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/4a/da/12/bucket-4ada1209069c7130d0b5b06928caaa0f824415e962e7a60a6bb485c99ee07fe3.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.514 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/de/af/8a/bucket-deaf8aeb4c53142864edd814425bb14a45fae3f36dea1557e88aae1c972e732b.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.514 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #1/32 in 2 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/10/04/21/bucket-100421672673d39259eac3b4b00e8c33cf35abbf28098a1c3ba4132fe34c69c6.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.514 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #1/32 in 2 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/4a/da/12/bucket-4ada1209069c7130d0b5b06928caaa0f824415e962e7a60a6bb485c99ee07fe3.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.514 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #1/32 in 2 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/de/af/8a/bucket-deaf8aeb4c53142864edd814425bb14a45fae3f36dea1557e88aae1c972e732b.xdr.gz
cp: cannot stat '/opt/stellar/history-cache/bucket/e6/f5/63/bucket-e6f563621f295d9df5a58f9ee69f1be358f3ba8aded02c127a314973decdc058.xdr.gz': No such file or directory
2019-02-22T12:04:46.515 GBRCX [Process WARNING] process 30125 exited 1: cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/bucket/e6/f5/63/bucket-e6f563621f295d9df5a58f9ee69f1be358f3ba8aded02c127a314973decdc058.xdr.gz buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2b62dacdf80bb2d4/bucket-e6f563621f295d9df5a58f9ee69f1be358f3ba8aded02c127a314973decdc058.xdr.gz.tmp
2019-02-22T12:04:46.515 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/e6/f5/63/bucket-e6f563621f295d9df5a58f9ee69f1be358f3ba8aded02c127a314973decdc058.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.516 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #1/32 in 1 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/e6/f5/63/bucket-e6f563621f295d9df5a58f9ee69f1be358f3ba8aded02c127a314973decdc058.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.547 GBRCX [Process WARNING] process 30120 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/bucket/8a/a5/81/bucket-8aa581c431b5d3bdd78ab0a2ce49ae8410ec0d96648aefae9883a9bc0e27662d.xdr.gz -o buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2b62dacdf80bb2d4/bucket-8aa581c431b5d3bdd78ab0a2ce49ae8410ec0d96648aefae9883a9bc0e27662d.xdr.gz.tmp
2019-02-22T12:04:46.547 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/8a/a5/81/bucket-8aa581c431b5d3bdd78ab0a2ce49ae8410ec0d96648aefae9883a9bc0e27662d.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.547 GBRCX [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #1/32 in 2 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/8a/a5/81/bucket-8aa581c431b5d3bdd78ab0a2ce49ae8410ec0d96648aefae9883a9bc0e27662d.xdr.gz
2019-02-22T12:04:46.554 GBRCX [Process WARNING] process 30121 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_002/bucket/ce/d7/88/bucket-ced7888c328cc0c4646d761233cfc0aa7982d931f723d2979aa98e563c17ab5c.xdr.gz -o buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2b62dacdf80bb2d4/bucket-ced7888c328cc0c4646d761233cfc0aa7982d931f723d2979aa98e563c17ab5c.xdr.gz.tmp
```

And it is stuck retrying and out of sync. The `info` endpoint on the core port says `"state" : "Joining SCP"`.

How do I get the core synced again?

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary issue with the archive at the time.